# rewrite batch file to powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch file that looks into a inf file and finds open= Open= or OPEN= and gets the program to run.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set _drive=W:
set _cmd=

cd /d !_drive!\
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%i in (autorun.inf) do (
  if "%%i"=="open" set _cmd=%%j
  if "%%i"=="Open" set _cmd=%%j
  if "%%i"=="OPEN" set _cmd=%%j
)
if not defined _cmd (
  echo Unable to parse autorun.inf and find 'open='
) else (
  !_drive!\!_cmd!
  START !_drive!
)

endlocal
```

I'm hoping someone out there is better at powershell then myself that can lead me in the right spot, as I've been looking around the web for a bit. so I should have mentioned this is [the OP here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362199/batch-file-for-autorun-inf)

Comment: please describe what it does - in detail. then almost anyone can use `Get-Help` and a few net searches to convert the description into PoSh code. [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

*Disclaimer: This was put together in a short time with some basic Googling. So there are likely more efficient and/or robust ways to approach the script below (e.g. by piping commands together).*

---

Assuming that you simply want to read an `autorun.inf` and start the `.exe` file (or what have you) found after e.g. `open=`, you may want to try something similar to the following:

*ex. Search_INF.ps1*

```
# Open "autorun.inf", search for a string containing ex. "open=", then perform
# actions based on the string found.

# --- Variables ---

$_drive = 'W:'
$_file = 'C:\path\to\autorun.inf'

# --- Main ---

# Use Select-String to find a given -Pattern in the $_file.
$_match = Select-String -Path $_file -List -Pattern 'open='

# Check the value of $_match.Line. If there were no matches (i.e. $_match.Line
# is $null), let the user know and exit the script.

if ($_match.Line -eq $Null) {

    Write-Output ''
    Write-Output 'Unable to parse autorun.inf and find "open="'
    Exit

}

# Returns just the matched string (ex. "open=program.exe") from $_match.
$_program = $_match.Line

# Slice off the first five characters (i.e. "open=") of e.g. "open=program.exe"
# (leaving just ex. "program.exe")
$_program = ($_program).Substring(5)

# Build the command string.
$_cmd = $_drive + '\' + $_program

# Start the program (ex. as "W:\program.exe")
START $_cmd

# Open the specified $_drive in Explorer. Equivalent to e.g. "start W:" in CMD.
CMD /C START $_drive
```

To run the script above, invoke `powershell` from the command line, ensuring you specify a path to the script e.g.:

```
powershell .\search_inf.ps1
```

(Assuming the command window was opened in the same directory as your `.ps1` file).

Be aware that Windows may not allow you to run PowerShell scripts until you specifically allow them.

---

**Notes**

- In the script above, `Select-String` initally sets `$_match` to e.g. `Path\to\autorun.inf:2:open=program.exe`.
- With the `-List` option, `Select-String` only returns the first instance of the matching text for the given input file.
- `open=` is case-insensitive (which is the default for `Select-String`, as far as I am aware). So it should cover `open=`, `Open=` and `OPEN=` in the original script.
- `open=` may instead be `shellexecute=` for some `autorun.inf` files.
- `$_match.Line` returns just the matched line (e.g. `open=program.exe`) rather than ex. `Path\to\autorun.inf:2:open=program.exe`.
- Based on cursory testing, the `CMD /C START $_drive` syntax appears to only work with bare drive letters (e.g. `W:`).
- `$_file = 'C:\path\to\autorun.inf'` is a placeholder. This could be e.g. `$_file = $_drive + '\autorun.inf'`, assuming `autorun.inf` resided in the root directory of ex. `W:\`.

---

**PowerShell Resources**

*Microsoft*

- *[Variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7)*
- *[Write-Output](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/Write-Output?view=powershell-7)*
- *[Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7)*
- *[MatchInfo Objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=pscore-6.2.0)*
- *[Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7)*

*ThinkPowerShell.com*

- *[$Null](https://thinkpowershell.com/test-powershell-variable-for-null-empty-string-and-white-space/)*

*StackOverflow.com*

- *[Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022326/terminating-a-script-in-powershell)*

*SS64.com*

- *[Substring](https://ss64.com/ps/substring.html)*

Answer (score 1):

**Powershell**. Short & sweet. Copy any command into a web serach to reaad the MS documentation.

### EDIT: Code improved to handle commandline arguments and check for 'ShellExecute' as well

```
$Drive = 'W:'
Set-Location $Drive
$Run = ( Get-Content autorun.inf | ?{ $_ -match 'Open=|ShellExecute=' }) -replace 'Open=' -replace 'ShellExecute='
If ( !($Run) ) {
    echo 'No "Open" or "ShellExecute" statement in the "autorun.inf" file.'
} Else {
    $Run = $Run.Split(' ')
    $Splat = @{ 'FilePath' = $Run[0] }
    If ($Run.Count -gt 1) {
        $Splat += @{ 'ArgumentList' = $Run[1..$Run.Count] }
    }
    Try {
        If ( Test-Path $Splat.FilePath ) {
            $Splat.FilePath = (Resolve-Path $Splat.FilePath).Path
            Start-Process @Splat
        } Else {
           echo "'$($Run[0])' is not a valid path to executeable."
        }
    } Catch {
        Echo "An error occured when attempting to run '$($Run[0])'"
    }
    explorer "."
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, see if you can shorten that to: `. ".\$Run"`. **PowerShell** always wants excutables to be specified by a path, even if just `.\<Name>`.

Comment: Without a real-world example, I was using `Notepad` for my `Open=` test. If the command has arguements, it might require more parsing. `Start-Process` is a better choice, but I was focused on proof-of-concept.

Comment: Awesome! Short and works well. =)

Comment: @anaksunaman: Once I get tweaking code, I can't stop! :D After looking at  [Autorun.inf Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/autorun-cmds?redirectedfrom=MSDN), I added a `.Split()` and a [@Splat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) and now it can handle commands that include arguments! :)

Comment: Lol I can definitely relate. =P Regarding the script, that's seems really useful. Nice addition. =)